# Why does the parameter -PointSize default value not get accepted by ImageMagick internally?

Tags: powershell

The following is function that lets me generate a image with a caption/text.

```
Function New-Image{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $Destination,
        
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Value,

        [string]$Dimentions,
        [int]$PointSize = 500,
        [string]$Font,
        [string]$FontColour,
        [string]$BackgroundColor,
        [string]$BorderColor,
        [String]$BorderStroke
    )
    $PSBoundParameters.Keys += If ($PSBoundParameters.Keys -notcontains 'PointSize'){"PointSize"}
    $magickArgs = @(
        switch ($PSBoundParameters.Keys){
            'PointSize'       { '-pointSize', $PointSize }
            'Font'            { '-font', $Font}
            'BackgroundColor' { '-background', $BackgroundColor}
            'FontColour'      { '-fill', $FontColour }
            'Value'           { "label:$value" }  # Exception: ONE token!
            'BorderColor'     { '-bordercolor', $BorderColor }
            'BorderStroke'    { '-border', $BorderStroke }
        }
    )
    $magickArgs
    . 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\magick.exe' @magickArgs $Destination
}
```

The parameter `-Pointsize`, lets me decide the image dimensions or font size of the text. I am finding myself using `-Pointsize 500` 95% of the time, so decided I would like to set `500` as the default value for this parameter.

But the way the function is designed (out of necessity for how PowerShell passes arguments to native commands) is making this hard for me to implement.

It seems with declaring `[String]$PointSize = 500,` right at the top, `-PointSize` does not get included in `$PSBoundParameters.Keys`, so the switch command never sees the `-Pointsize` parameter.

I fixed this with   `$PSBoundParameters.Keys += If ($PSBoundParameters.Keys -notcontains 'PointSize'){"PointSize"}`
yet whenever I carry out a test with:

```
New-Image "hellow world" -Destination "test3.png"
```

The text is still very small,  as if ImageMagick never received the `-PointSize` parameter and value, but printing `$magicArgs` clearly shows it has:

```
New-Image "hellow world" -Destination "test3.png"  

label:hellow world   # Output
-pointSize  
500
```

Manually declaring `-PointSize` with a value of `500` works fine. The text of the generate image is very large.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ```$psboundparameters.Keys += "PointSize"``` is equivalent to ```$psboundparameters[“Keys”] = "PointSize"``` - you’re setting a key called “Keys” with a value “PointSize”, *not* setting a key called “PointSize”. You shouldn’t really modify ```$PSBoundParameters``` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#long-description, but you if you ignore that (at your peril) could do ```$PSBoundParameters[“PointSize] = $PointSize```.

Comment: Good points, @mclayton, but there's a difference between trying to _assign to_ an automatic variable (i.e. assigning a _different object_ - which is definitely ill-advised - and _modifying the object that it contains_, which in this particular case is explicitly mentioned as a possibility (from the linked topic, emphasis added): "You can use it [`$PSBoundParameters`] to display _or change_ the current values of parameters or to pass parameter values to another script or function."

Comment: @mklement0 - ah, yeah. The devil’s in the details again. Thanks for correcting :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) only contains *explicitly* bound parameters and their values (i.e. those supplied by the caller), which notably doesn't include *default* values.

- This behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #3285](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3285), from the perspective of wanting default values *included*.

You had the right idea - adding a `PointSize` entry with the desired default value to `$PSBoundParameters` if the caller didn't pass a `-PointSize` argument - but the implementation was flawed; use the following instead:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('PointSize')) {
  $PSBoundParameters['PointSize'] = $PointSize
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

```bash
# !! Adds an entry whose key is literally "Keys", 
# !! with literal value "PointSize"
$PSBoundParameters.Keys += If ($PSBoundParameters.Keys -notcontains 'PointSize'){"PointSize"}
```

Even conceptually trying to *assign* to the - read-only - `.Keys` property wouldn't work: only the `.Add()` method and index syntax / dot notation (see below) can be used to grow the dictionary, by adding whole *entries* - whose keys are then automatically reflected in the `.Keys` collection.

What PowerShell - perhaps surprisingly - does is when you assign to `.Keys` is that it creates a *new entry* whose literal key value is `Keys`, because - as a syntactic convenience - *dot notation* can be used in lieu of *index notation*; that is, `$PSBoundParameters.Keys = ...` is equivalent to `$PSBoundParameters['Keys'] = ...`

In other words: your attempt created a new entry with literal key `Keys` and literal value `PointSize`, meaning that the entry has both the wrong key (it should be `PointSize`) and value (it should be the value of `$PointSize`).

---

<sup>[1] Note that is *generally* not a good idea to modify the objects that *automatic* variables point to, but in this particular case it is explicitly mentioned as a possibility (from the help topic linked at the top, emphasis added): "You can use it [`$PSBoundParameters`] to display *or change* the current values of parameters or to pass parameter values to another script or function."

By contrast, it is *never* a good idea (and often fails) to *assign a different value* to an automatic variable (e.g, `$PSBoundParameters = ...`)</sup>

Comment: One (vanishingly small) corner case where it would make a difference is if you’re splatting $PSBoundParameters down into a function with similar parameters but *different* default values - semantically passing a “missing” parameter key would adopt the “inner” default value in the inner function rather than passing the “outer” function’s default down

Comment: @mclayton, yes, that's why it would be nice to at least have the option to include the enclosing script/function's default parameter values when splatting `@PSBoundParameteres` (possibly via a different, yet-to-be-introduced automatic variable).